# Are skill points spent on upgrades to Elven Rage refunded upon entering Act 4?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-war

My approach to spending skill points has been a bit sloppy, and I have no idea if I even spent any of my points in Elven Rage in the 1st 3 acts of the game.  But I did notice that when Act 4 starts that 2 new skills are added and that one of them took the place of a former skill.  After a bit of research, I've discovered that the lost skill is Elven Rage.  Honestly, I didn't use it much anyway.

So, does anyone know if points spent to upgrade Elven Rage go to the gone-forever-place, or are they refunded when (un)life changes for Talion?

Comment: Thanks for not completely spoiling this. I really need to get through this game but I'm having too much fun with fortresses and collectibles.

Comment: @Twobe7, FWIW, I'm still having fun w/ fortresses & collectables in Act 4.  Heck, I'm pretty sure that's the better part of the game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Skill Points invested to Elven Rage abilities are lost.**

I had invested skill points to all three abilities previous to Act 4 (two were purely to answer this question).
On commencing Act 4, there was no change in my spare skill points.